# Perl Tk Canvas - Is it possible to escape characters in tag expressions?

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit, tkinter-canvas

I have a Tk Canvas which I'm using to display electrical relay circuits. As part of updating the Canvas, I use `itemcget()` to get the current state of some objects in the Canvas. For example:

```
$CW->itemcget("COIL$name", '-fill')
```

The issue is that when displaying certain circuits, I get the following error and the canvas stops updating:

```
=== 20092 === Tk::Error: Invalid boolean operator in tag search expression at C:\Strawberry\perl\site\lib/Tk.pm line 251.
```

The offending tag is something like "COIL[!AB*CD[F]]Zyx123". Tk interprets the '!' as a logical NOT, which makes this an invalid expression. Removing the '!' from `$name` in the `itemcget()` call stops the error, but has the obvious downside that it can no longer find the right tag. I couldn't find any documented way to escape characters in a tag expression, so I tried adding a backslash before the '!', which didn't work. Neither did adding a second '!'.

Is there any way to escape the '!' in the tag expression, or am I going to have to re-work the code so that tag names never contain these characters?

EDIT: I ended up going with a third option. I wrote a function that searches every object in a Canvas for one with a matching tag, bypassing the tag expression problem.

```
sub canvas_tag_search
{
    my ($CW, $search_tag) = @_;
    
    foreach my $object ($CW->find('all'))
    {
        foreach my $tag ($CW->gettags($object))
        {
            if ($tag eq $search_tag)
            {
                return $object;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return undef;  # No match found
}
```

This solution doesn't address my original question, but it will work for my purposes.

Comment: You can switch to `*` or some other meaningless character. Enclosing the exclamation mark in double quotes works, too, but you need to do that in the tag, as well.

Comment: @choroba Neither of those work. Swapping ! for * has the same problem as removing it (stops the error, but no longer finds the tag), and changing the tag is precisely what I'm trying to avoid. That will require a significant amount of re-working, so I'd like to verify that there's no easier option first.

Comment: It works for me with the `*` as well as `a"!"b` or `"a!b"`.

Comment: It works like that if you change it in the tag definition as well...

Comment: Exactly. I didn't find a way to force tk to stop interpreting a bare `!` as a negation. I checked the Tk source, but I haven't looked at the tk source.

Comment: perldoc Tk::Canvas talks about the logical expressions that can be performed on tags.  In addition to `!`, you also can't use `&&`, `||`, or `^` as part of names. `current`, and `all` are also reserved.